# direction of force on a conductive stick moving in magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism

If I drop a conductive stick down a homogenous uniform magnetic field, does it experience a force? Or are just electrons and protons experiencing opposite equal forces that lead to no net force on a stick?

Oddly enough, everyone is only talking about current carrying wires or closed loops of wires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why

> everyone is only talking about current carrying wires or closed loops
>   of wires

is because Lenz's law states that the direction of the induced **current** is such as to try and oppose the motion producing it.
If you have no current you have no opposition to the motion.

So your stick will have some changes moving along it if it is cutting magnetic field lines and eventually there will be opposite charges at each end of the stick which will produce an electric field in the stick which prevents further charges moving.

During this phase the stick falls at a slight slower rate and some of the gravitational potential energy lost by the stick is used to set up the stick's electric potential energy.
The slower rate of fall is the opposition to the motion of the stick which is producing the motion of charges along the stick (current).

As soon as the charges stop moving ie there is no current, even though there is a motional emf across the stick there will be no opposition to the movement of the stick.

Comment: Can I ask you then, why if we have 2 wires next to eachother conducting current in the same direction, do we get attractive force between them EVEN THOUGH current density is biggest away from the other wire. If attractive force is being caused by attraction of electrons in the other wire by magnetism, then why are electrons pushed away from the other wire instead of towards it. I've seen this result from FEM simulations.

Comment: When you have the wires conducting current in the same direction there is no accumulation of charge anywhere along the wires and thus there is no electrostatic force of repulsion and due to the magnetic field they produce there is a force of attraction between them. There is a diagram of the magnetic field pattern here http://www.physchem.co.za/OB11-ele/magnetic1.htm

Comment: The problem is I'm trying to go deeper into understanding this phenomena. I understand why the wires attract eachother. This is because electrons from one wire are acting magneticaly on moving electrons in the other. The direction of that force is attractive. But if electron are attracted to the other wire, they should be pushed towards other wire, not away from it, which according to the FEM simulations happens. The current density increases away from the other wire instead of towards it. Something is pushing the electrons away, so how can they force the wire towards the other wire? :D

Answer (score 0):

To experience a magnetic force, the charges must move in the magnetic field.

Although the electrons in the conductive stick are able to move, they won't move on their own i.e: a potential (through a battery) has to be applied across the conductive stick to make the electrons move. This movement of the electrons in the magnetic field causes them to experience a magnetic force.

$\vec{F} = q\vec{v}\times \vec{B}$

where $\vec{v}$ is the velocity of the electron, $\vec{B}$ is the magnetic field and $q$ is the charge on the electron.

Thus, $F = 0$ if $v$ or $B$ is zero, or $\vec{v}$ is parallel (or anti-parallel) to $\vec{B}$.
$$$$
For a wire,

$\vec{F} = I\vec{L}\times \vec{B}$

where $I$ is the current in the wire, $\vec{B}$ is the magnetic field and $\vec{L}$ is the length of the wire with the direction to be along the direction of current.

Thus, if $I = 0$, $F = 0$

Comment: Forget the battery. When I move a stick, electrons move with it, so charges ARE moving. The effect is that electrons move to one side untill they are equaly countered by electrostatic force they produce, while protons can't move, but they experience the opposite force. The net force on the stick should be 0 after the transient effect. What I want to know, is the stick feeling any force while moving trough a uniform magnetic field? Like a counter force? Or does it experience no force at all, and all that happens is a voltage get's induced across the stick?

Comment: If the stick is given a certain velocity...Then, yes, the electrons in the stick will experience a force. In fact, this movement results in formation of an emf which is known as motional emf.

Comment: @BhavyaSharma "Although the electrons in the conductive stick are able to move, they won't move on their own i.e: a potential (through a battery) has to be applied across the conductive stick to make the electrons move": The electrons are always in motion but the vector sum of their velocities yields zero. A potential difference causes the electrons to move in order in a particular direction. The electrons collide and rebound continuously but the vector sum of the velocities is non-zero.